# matplotlib: Centering period labels under the period's data in a time-series plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

matplotlib's axis-formatting options tend to fall flat when it comes to plotting and effectively labeling dense time-series data.

One problem is that tick labels are tied to ticks, so if you set axis ticks at an appropriate frequency, there are usually too many labels. This also means that if you are plotting, say, daily data over a period of several years, there is no good way to label the x-axis with each year in its natural position: centered under the year's data (i.e., under the x-axis position for July 2, or thereabouts).

The trick described in [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/centered_ticklabels.html)—set major ticks where you want them, then use invisible minor ticks to place the labels elsewhere—works, but it limits you to one visible set of axis ticks (since each axis is limited to one set of major and one set of minor ticks).  You can't show, say, major ticks at the start of each year and minor ticks at the start of each month without giving up the ability to put year labels centered appropriately between the major (yearly) ticks, as you would find in publication-quality plots.

Is there a work-around that doesn't involve drawing everything fully manually?

Comment: While I'll agree that matplotlib's tick labeling could be more flexible, the type of labeling you're describing only requires two or three lines of code... It's quite simple to do manually with `annotate`.

Comment: depending on the nature of your data, you may want to look at www.rrdtool.org ... it does quite a good job labeling the x-axis (I think).

Comment: Has anything happened here in the last years? I have the same issue as pash and have not found anything satisfying. You would think it should not be such a problem to include an option for something like this in the code. So if anybody has an solution I would also be happy to hear :) - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the tsplot capability in [scikits.timeseries](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/lib.plotting.examples.html)? It hasn't been maintained much recently, but it works pretty well. I'll be porting that code into pandas at some point in the relative near future.

Comment: Wes, `tsplot` interacts with a subclass of matplotlib's `Subplot`, so it offers exactly the same features (and lack thereof) in this regard. Thanks for your great work on pandas, BTW. It's a great library that I use often.

Comment: Did you part this to pandas in the end? :)